# Issue about Binary search algorithm in c

Tags: c, algorithm, int, declaration, binary-search

I am confused in understating the behavior of the code  **while searching for an element which does not exist in the array**.

1. The result of the element index i am looking for is always zero while declaring it as `int index;`.
2. The result of the element index i am looking for is random number while declaring it as `size_t index;`
   what is the difference between declaring the variable index as `int index;` and`size_t;`in the code below.

**The code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5
int main(void)
{
    int numbers[SIZE]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int search =0; // This variable define the required number i am searching for 
    int start = 0 ;
    int end = SIZE-1 ;
    size_t index;
    while (start <= end)
    {
        int middle = (start+end)/2;
        if  (search == numbers[middle])
        {
            index = middle;
        }
        if (search > numbers[middle])
        {
            start = middle+1 ;
        }
        else
        {
            end= middle-1 ;
        }
    }
    printf("The index of the element is %d",index);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%d` is not the right format specifier for printing a `size_t`.

Comment: `index = middle;` --> `index = middle; break;` Also `size_t index;` uninitialized. --> `size_t index = SIZE;` (`SIZE` meant "Not found")

Comment: what is the right specifier for size_t ?@Hurkyl

Comment: For C-Standard conforming implementations use `zu`. On windows use `lu`.

Comment: when there is no data found `index` not setting any value hence both `int` & `size_t` initialize by anything (this is undefined behavior) . Try to set default value when initialize `index`

Comment: `search`, `start` and `end` should as well be of `size_t`.

Comment: Also skip everything if `SIZE`  is less or equal `1`.

Comment: @alk `start <= end` when `start`:0, `end`:0 ==> end=end-1 ==> `start <= end` become true. (not break loop)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Yes, well, still this should be solvable without negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem is that `index` is not initialized and that it never gets assigned when you don't find what you are searching for. Since the `printf` statement accesses an uninitialized variable in that case, your code have undefined behavior, i.e. anything may happen - including print of all sorts of numbers.

> The result of the element index i am looking for is always zero while declaring it as int index;

That is "just by luck"

> The result of the element index i am looking for is random number while declaring it as size_t index;

That is also "just by luck"

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of action items you can take to improve your code:

1. Since this array is statically defined there is no need to include the `SIZE` define inside the `[]`.  Declare it like this `int numbers[]={1,2,3,4,5};` instead of this `int numbers[SIZE]={1,2,3,4,5};`.  Let the compiler do the math for you.
2. Initialize `index` to some value (i.e. `index = 0;`).  this is the **main cause of the problem** and it is introducing undefined behavior to the program.
3. Change the type of `size_t index` to `int index` every variable that was declared in the program is an `int` and the program is treating `index` as an `int`. So it might as well be an `int` to avoid confusion.
4. Make this an `else if` clause instead of just an `if`:

   ```
   else if (search > numbers[middle])
   {
       start = middle+1 ;
   }
   ```
5. Add another case to have the program fail gracefully when the value to be searched is missing from the data set. Such as, `printf("Data not found: %d", search);`

The algorithm still isn't 100% and has some flaws but I will leave this up to you to figure out.  I hope this info helps!

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that , the value of `index`is not initialized.

initializing the variable to 0 does not solve your problem.
Because you are using `index` to return the position of the array element.

By initializing the `index = 0`  will provide he same result for the elements not present in the array as well as the for the first element to the of the array .

The better way is to initialize as `size_t index = -1;`

So that the result for the elements not present in the array would b -1.

Also  check for the access specifier used in the printf statement, for size_t datatype. It can be ,

```
printf("The index of the element is %ld",index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correct specifier for size_t, it's not %d.

Try to use %zd or %ld and it'll work fine.

Furthermore, add this after the while loop so that it doesn't show weird value of index when the element is not present in the array.

```
if(start>end) {
   printf("That number is not present in the array");
   return 0;
}
```

And move the line `printf("The index of the element is %d",index);` under the condition `if  (search == numbers[middle])`. So that you don't get "this number is not present" even if it is present in the array.
For corrected version of your code see https://code.hackerearth.com/80043dg?key=7b325b26aec0f5425b76cc3efbdc93cf

Comment: i have changed the specifier but the same behavior @sanjay-sopho

Comment: i am not asking about how to display the result in the right way as i know ,and your code need some modification@ Sanjay-sopho

Comment: @Elhaw Please tell me where my code needs modification. I suppose my code is giving the correct expected output hence it's correct.

Comment: your condition does guarantee the correct output of the code as the out always  That number is not present in the array